# Array is not an array anymore after getting stringified and parsed (JSON)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

After that I stringified my array I parsed it, I then tried to acces one of the elements inside the array (array[number]) but it seems that the elements in the array are all mashed as one or something like that. I would like to know why and how to change this. Thanks in advance!

```
var linkrecup = localStorage.getItem('linksstring');
JSON.parse(linkrecup);
alert(linkrecup);
var linkarr = [''+linkrecup+''];
alert(linkarr.length); // this gives '1'
var div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.id = 'placememe'+memenumber+'';
div.className = 'meme';
var nombrememes = document.getElementsByClassName("meme").length;
alert(nombrememes);
var crpt = nombrememes - 1;
alert(crpt);
alert(linkarr[3]); // this gives 'undefined'
```

Every var that is used is declared in another piece of code, if you want it just ask and I'll gladly give it to you.

EDIT: So basically what im doing (trying) with this code to do is to push a link that is given by the user (prompt) and add it to the array of links that already have some links stored in (.push) then stock it (the whole array) in localStorage (stringified with JSON.stringify) then re-acces this array later (with a localStorage.getItem) then parse it (JSON.parse) and then use one of the elements of the array (link) as the link for an image. Here's the code with the stringify and shit.

```
var newmeme = prompt('Please paste the link of the meme below!');
memes.push ('placememe'+memenumber+'');
links.push (newmeme);
var div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.id = 'placememe'+memenumber+'';
div.className = 'meme';
var nombrememes = document.getElementsByClassName("meme").length;
var vrb = nombrememes - 1;
div.innerHTML = '<img src="'+links[vrb]+'" width="700" height="700" alt="" />';

var linksstring = links
localStorage.setItem('linksstring',JSON.stringify(linksstring));
var linkrecup = localStorage.getItem('linksstring');
JSON.parse(linkrecup);
alert(linkrecup);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what your code is trying to do. In particular, what is the intention of `[''+linkrecup+'']`?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/move ? It would help as to help you, as we wouldn't have to guess the data structure and write our own testing environment...

Comment: Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation of what you are trying to accomplish and what expected results are. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: Can you post the code where you use `localStorage.set` or at least tell us whether the data saved is an array or object?

Comment: What you want is `var linkarr = JSON.parse(linkrecup)`

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(object) returns a parsed object

Try using

> var parsedlinkrecup=JSON.parse(linkrecup)